# Which books should I follow?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Can anyone suggest me good books , for analysis , which can help me in my tifr exam , books should contain real analysis and complex analysis

Comment: I am not familiar with the TIFR exams, what level are you suggesting? Measure theoretic (modern) analysis or classical analysis?

Comment: Sir it is basically on classical analysis

Comment: Oldies but goodies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Complex Analysis my favorite book is "A Course in Complex Analysis"- Fischer and Lieb. For Real Analysis I suggest you the Baby-Rudin or Real Analysis-Sullivan and Haaser.

Answer (score 0):

Princeton Lectures in Analysis is a good choice for undergrad level analysis.
Here is the link for book 3: Real Analysis:
[https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Integration-Princeton-Lectures/dp/0691113866](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113866)